# Find missing trailing commas in array

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm

I would find every missing comma from every array(PHP Style)

Find this

```
array(
    'example',
    'example'
);
```

And fix them

```
array(
    'example',
    'example',
);
```

I would put the regex directly in PhpStorm but my try on online regex wasn't successful

Note: This is not a `.php` file, `CTRL+ALT+L` Reformat Code do not work

I would at least find them, if there a tips to also fix them i take it !

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [@CD001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886824/cd001) who come up with `/array\([^\)]*\'\s*\);/gs` that almost perfect !

His solution fail on this sample

```
->setSomething(array(
    'example',
    'example'
));
```

This is **optionnal**, like [@CD001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886824/cd001) said  that also raises the question of there not being a `'` mark before the closing `)`

Sample

```
->setSomething(array(
    new Test,
    'example'
));

->setSomething(array
    'example',
    new Test
));
```

If there a regex guru here :)
Also a code snippet is available here : https://regex101.com/r/aKfZC9/4/

Comment: What's the file extension if it's not `.php`? You could just change the extension to `.php`, reformat the code, and then set the extension back to the original extension.

Comment: Why don't you post your regex

Comment: Ummmm... as a PHP array, your first example is actually correct.

Comment: @CD001 both are correct. Some place the `,` at the end of every element to allow them to be easily appended to (when done manually)

Comment: You can use https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer for fixing this code, see the `trailing_comma_in_multiline_array` option.

Comment: @CD001 Sure it's valid, but that not what I want

Comment: @ctwheels .rst reStructedText, it's will reformat too many things

Comment: If you need a regexp to match the first array but not the second, try: `/array\(.*\'\s*\);/gs` (you'll need the `s` pattern modifier to match across multiple lines) - that only matches when there's nothing except whitespace between the final `'` and the closing parenthesis (e.g. **not** `'example',)`)

Comment: @CD001 That almost perfect ! but if somewhere i got `myFunction('test', 'test');` this is also match, i would only scope in array

Comment: Unless your function is called something like `myFunctionarray()` you should be OK as it specifically matches the string `array(` beforehand - try it out at: https://regex101.com/r/VEkIC2/1

Comment: @CD001 This do not work like i would, it's match everything after he found one, snippet with your regex https://regex101.com/r/aKfZC9/2

Comment: Ah gotcha, [try this](https://regex101.com/r/Gl2SSa/1): `/array\([^\)]*\'\s*\);/gs`

Comment: @CD001 Almost ! this do not match the last array from my snippet :)

Comment: Missed that - and that also raises the question of there not being a `'` mark before the closing `)` - e.g. `array(new Test())` ... needs a rethink :|

Comment: @CD001 That my fault, my sample wans't good enought, i will edit the main post to be more clear

Comment: I think you cant solve your problem with regex. Because you can have nested parenthesis like: `array('test' => new Handler(new Reader()))`.

Comment: You want to use a token parser, not a regular expression. [`phpcs`](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) should be able to do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added some extra samples and extended the regex by [@CD001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886824/cd001) in your example: https://regex101.com/r/ukPbft/1

Assuming you don't want to match short array syntax and match arrays anywhere in a function call (meaning it won't necessarily be followed by a semi colon), the regex would look like this:

```
/array\((?!\s*\)+)[^\)]+(?<!,|,\s)\)/gs
```

But for PHPStorm, you'll need it in this format:

```
array\((?!\s*\)+)[^\)]+(?<!,|,\s)\)
```

> **Explanation**
>
> **array\(** - Match the opening 'array(' tag.
>
> **(?!\s*\)+)** - A positive lookahead to make sure the array doesn't just consist of spaces between the opening and closing brackets, so it doesn't match 'array( )'.
>
> **[^\)]+** - Make sure there's at least one character before the closing bracket, so it doesn't match 'array()'
>
> **(?<!,|,\s)** - A negative lookbehind to make sure there's no comma **or** whitespace preceded by a comma at the end of the array declaration
>
> **\)** - Match the closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is correct. The second example, php ignores the last entry.

```
$x = array("example1","example2");
: array = 
  0: string = example1
  1: string = example2
$y = array("example1","example2",);
: array = 
  0: string = example1
  1: string = example2
$x1 = count($x);
: long = 2
$y1 = count($y);
: long = 2
```